# how to dynamically rewrite filepath .htaccess based on domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this apache rule in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testURL.localhost.local
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /_testURL/index.php [L]
```

How would I write this so that testURL2.localhost.local or any other subdomain would be rewritten to the corresponding directories?

For instance `testURL2.localhost.local` would be rewritten  to `_testURL2/index.php` etc

I already tried the option below but I didn't get the intended result:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testURL
RewriteRule ^cms.php$ /_%1/cms.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, attempts; please try following htaccess rules file. I have posted 2 sets of htaccess rules file here, you have to use ONLY one set at a time.

***1st solution:*** This is specifically for host testURL.localhost.local and will look for either index.php OR cms.php only in UI.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(testURL)\.localhost\.local$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?:index|cms)\.php)$  _%1/$1 [NC,L]
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** A Generic solution, where it will look for `anyvalue`.localhost.local and it will add `anyvalue` in path while rewriting, also it will look for any php files in uri.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^.]*)\.localhost\.local$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]*\.php)$  _%1/$1 [NC,L]
```

***NOTE1:*** Also please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

***NOTE2:*** Please keep these rules at the top of your htaccess rules file.

***NOTE3:*** I am also additionally/optimally  matching `www.` in host in case you don't want it you could remove it `(?:www\.)?` part in condition.